# Should I worry that using GET in a form element doesn't automatically URL-encode angle brackets?

Tags: javascript, security, get, webmatrix, url-encoding

So I decided to use GET in my form element, point it to my cshtml page, and found (as expected) that it automatically URL encodes any passed form values.

I then, however, decided to test if it encodes angle brackets and surprisingly found that it did not when the WebMatrix validator threw a server error warning me about a potentially dangerous value being passed.

I said to myself, "Okay, then I guess I'll use `Request.Unvalidated["searchText"]` instead of `Request.QueryString["searchText"]`. Then, as any smart developer who uses `Request.Unvalidated` does, I tried to make sure that I was being extra careful, but I honestly don't know much about inserting JavaScript into URLs so I am not sure if I should worry about this or not.  I have noticed that it encodes apostrophes, quotations, parenthesis, and many other JavaScript special characters (actually, I'm not even sure if an angle bracket even has special meaning in JavaScript OR URLs, but it probably does in one, if not both. I know it helps denote a List in C#, but in any event you can write script tags with it if you could find a way to get it on the HTML page, so I guess that's why WebMatrix's validator screams at me when it sees them).

Should I find another way to submit this form, whereas I can intercept and encode the user data myself, or is it okay to use `Request.Unvalidated` in this instance without any sense of worry?

Please note, as you have probably already noticed, my question comes from a WebMatrix C#.net environment.

Bonus question (if you feel like saving me some time and you already know the answer off the top of your head): If I use `Request.Unvalidated` will I have to URL-decode the value, or does it do that automatically like `Request.QueryString` does?

**---------------------------UPDATE----------------------------**

Since I know I want neither a YSOD nor a custom error page to appear simply because a user included angle brackets in their "searchText", I know I have to use `Request.Unvalidated` either way, and I know I can encode whatever I want once the value reaches the cshtml page.

**So I guess the question *really* becomes:** Should I worry about possible XSS attacks (or any other threat for that matter) inside the URL based on angle brackets alone?

Also, in case this is relevant:

Actually, the value I am using (i.e. "searchText") goes straight to a cshtml page where the value is ran through a (rather complex) SQL query that queries many tables in a database (using both JOINS and UNIONS, as well as Aliases and function-based calculations) to determine the number of matches found against "searchText" in each applicable field. Then I remember the page locations of all of these matches, determine a search results order based on relevance (determined by type and number of matches found) and finally use C# to write the search results (as links, of course) to a page.

And I guess it is important to note that the database values could easily contain angle brackets. I know it's safe so far (thanks to HTML encoding), but I suppose it may not be necessary to actually "search" against them. I am confused as to how to proceed to maximum security and functional expecations, but if I choose one way or the other, I may not know I chose the wrong decision until it is much too late...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**URL and special caracters**

The url `http://test.com/?param="><script>alert('xss')</script>` is "benign" until it is read and ..

1. print in a template : `Hello @param`. (Potential reflected/persisted XSS)
2. or use in Javascript : `divContent.innerHTML = '<a href="' + window.location.href + ...` (Potential DOM XSS)

Otherwise, the browser doesn't evaluate the query string as html/script.

**Request.Unvalidated/Request.QueryString**

You should use Request.Unvalidated["searchText"] if you are expecting to receive special caracters.
For example : `<b>User content</b><p>Some text...</p>`

If your application is working as expected with QueryString["searchText"], you should keep it since it validate for potential XSS.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.unvalidated.aspx

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I can't just "accept" server-side errors. I mean, I know the configurations in my web.config file are set to (as it is by default) not show *what* the error actually is, but it is still too ugly to accept. Also, yes I know you can (although, I don't yet know how) set a default error page, which I pretty much know I must do, anyway, so it won't ultimately be that ugly, but it seems an entire "Oops!" error page is still a bit much for a simple search string that contains angle brackets.

Comment: With both options, you need to properly escape the output. There are few cases were it will be tricky to escape (if you include the value in a JavaScript for example). The XSS protection is good to catch some forgoten outputs.

Comment: Actually, the value I am using (i.e. "searchText") goes straight to a cshtml page where the value is ran through a (rather complex) SQL query that queries many tables in a database (using both JOINS and UNIONS, as well as Aliases and function-based calculations) to determine the number of matches the against "searchText" in each applicable field. Then I remember the page locations of all of these matches, determine a search results order based on relevance (determined by type and number of matches found) and finally use C# to write the search results (as links, of course) to a page.

Comment: And I guess it is important to note that the database values could easily contain angle brackets. I know it's safe so far (thanks to HTML encoding), but I suppose it may not be necessary to actually "search" against them. I am confused as to how to proceed to maximum security and functional expecations, but if I choose one way or the other, I may not know I chose the wrong decision until it is much too late...

Comment: So I guess the question really becomes: Should I worry about possible XSS attacks (or any other threat for that matter) inside the URL based on angle brackets alone?

Comment: Without code sample, it is hard to comment. Possible XSS can occurs with Request.Unvalidated or Request.QueryString. The SQL query can cause problem also. Make sure you're query is build using prepare statement or a proper sanitization and you'll be able to pass any characters.

Comment: I'm not worried about anything beyond the question of whether or not angle brackets alone, within a url alone, is a security risk.  I know how to encode for HTML, URLs, XML, etc., as well as how to use parameterized queries to negate the security threat of SQL injection. The problem is, using "GET" in the form never lets me do anything to the user data until after it is being used in the URL, and I have heard (although, I have never made a successful attempt) that a possible XSS vector can be the URL in itself (i.e., javascript can be run from the url alone).

Comment: Javascript can't be executed from URL alone. Parameters are either printed in the page (Reflected/Persisted XSS) or read by Javascript (DOM XSS).

Comment: Okay, I suppose I misunderstood what I read then. It seems then, that I have nothing to worry about with just angle brackets alone, since functionally, it works fine. That is useful, thank you. Please include that in your answer so I can accept.